# Showing toast message with MBProgressHUD in mac os

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, mbprogresshud

I am showing toast message using `MBProgressHUD` but with toast message getting some view with it Below is code is using

[image: HUD image]

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window.contentView animated:YES];;

// Configure for text only and offset down
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
hud.labelText = @"some message......";
hud.margin = 10.f;
hud.yOffset = 200.f;
hud.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
[hud hide:YES afterDelay:20];
```

Comment: You need to add more context to your question as it seems to be a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @VijaySanghavi i have button when click on it i want to show some toast message the code that i am using i have provided above and the output which i am getting i attached image.

Comment: @iMHiteshSurani MBProgressHUD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For macOS Using `MBProgressHud` you can show like this

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:window.contentView];
            hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
            hud.labelFont = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
            hud.margin = 8.f;
            hud.opacity = 0.7;
            hud.yOffset = NSHeight(window.frame)/2-60;
            hud.cornerRadius = 4.0;
            hud.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
            hud.detailsLabelText = @"some message......";
            [window.contentView addSubview:hud];
            [hud show:YES];
            [hud hide:YES afterDelay:2.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
- (void)showLoader:(NSString*)strTitle view:(UIView*)view
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() , ^{
        MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:view.window];
        [view.window addSubview:hud];
        hud.labelText = strTitle;
        [hud show:YES];
    });
}
```

**Use like this:**

```
[self showLoader:@"Loading.." view:self.view]
```

Answer (score 0):

//JUST REPLACE YOUR CODE AND CHECK

```
AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:appDel.window animated:YES];
```